# Managing REST endpoints in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Is there a best practice to store and manage all REST endpoints for an application at one location within Angular JS?

Comment: Store all URL in js file defined by `var` and include that file to all file where API endpoint is required and use variable it directly. __OR__ you can use constant service of angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them as constants outside application, according to [this great document](https://12factor.net/config).

You can store such config as

**env.js**

```
(function (window) {
    window.__env = window.__env || {};

    // Login page address
    window.__env.loginUrl = 'http://website/login';

}(this));
```

then assign it as a constant in your main module

**app.js**

```
angular.module('yourmodule', [])
    .constant('__env', __env)
```

and then you can inject in in your service

`loginData.$inject = ['$http', '__env'];`

Such configuration works best for me, is easy to manage and change depending on environment, without rebuilding application. Just assigning `constant` doesn't have such advantage.

Answer (score 1):

In **AngularJS**

```
app.value('config', {
  "baseUrl": "http://www.some.url"
});
```

and access it with

```
config.baseUrl + "/fetchAll.json"
```

> Do not forget to inject dependency `config`.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, how do you replace the placeholder values such as parameter values for eg I have a REST URL /rest/person/{person-id}/address . In this case I want person-id to come in from code and replace the place holder value.

Comment: `config.baseUrl + "/rest/person/" + person-id + "/address"`

Answer (score 1):

A Generic One which I am comfortable using:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ConnectionService', function ($http, $log) {
    var connectionurl = 'http://localhost:8000/Services.svc/';
    return {
        connectionurl: connectionurl,

        getData:function(successCallBack){
             $http({
                   method: 'GET',
        /********HERE COMES YOUR REST WebGet or WebInvoke URI************/
                   url: connectionurl+ 'methodname'
             })
             .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                successCallBack(data);
           })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            })
          }
     });
```

You can use this ConnectionService in your controller as

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SampleController',
          function ($scope,ConnectionService){
                    ConnectionService.getData(function(response){
                    $scope.object=response;
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for all REST definitions.